# $f(x-y+z) > f(x) - f(y) + f(z)$ for $x<y<z$ if $f$ is concave?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

While studying the original literature of the Hausdorff-Measure "Dimension und äußeres Maß" (1918), on page 168 there is given the inequality
$$f(x-y+z) > f(x) - f(y) + f(z) \text{ for } x < y < z.$$
Since the publication is pretty long ago and it's written in a strange style, I'm not quite sure which conditions $f$ needs to fulfill. I guess it needs to be a concave (convex upwards) function, at least for simple examples it seems to work. But I can't find a proof for this statement.

I would be very happy if someone could say whether this statement is correct and in the best case could provide proof for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct that the inequality holds for concave function. It is a special case of [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality).

- If $y \ge x+z-y$ then $(z, x)$ majorizes $(y, x+z-y)$ because $z \ge y$ and $z+x = y + (x+z-y)$.
- Otherwise $(z, x)$ majorizes $(x+z-y, y)$.

In both cases, for a concave function $f$ it follows that
$$
 f(z) + f(x) \le f(y) + f(x+z-y) \, .
$$
If $f$ is strictly concave then the inequality is strict.

---

You can also derive it directly by writing down the concavity condition for $x < y < z$
$$
 f(y) \ge \frac{z-y}{z-x}f(x) + \frac{y-x}{z-x}f(z)
$$
and for $x < x+z-y < z$
$$
 f(x+z-y) \ge \frac{y-x}{z-x}f(x) + \frac{z-y}{z-x}f(z)
$$
and add these two inequalities. Again, the inequalities are strict if $f$ is strictly concave.

Comment: 1) Following your remark (I thank you for it), I have erased my answer. 2) I agree with your second proof, but for the first one, the use you make of Karamata's inequality is not clear to me, as we want to prove that $f$ is concave. In particular (it is not given in the Wikipedia article) it should be stated under which form Karamata's inequality provides a necessary and sufficient condition of concavity. But may be there is something I have skipped...

Comment: @JeanMarie: I have only shown that if $f$ is concave then the inequality holds, which is what the question asks in the title. I am not sure if the question's body is really meant to be asking for the opposite direction, but if the inequality holds for all $x < y < z$ then setting $y =(x+z)/2$ shows that $f$ is midpoint-concave. If we assume that $f$ is continuous (or bounded or Borel measurable) then it follows that $f$ is concave.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks.